# Clean Project shortcut in Android Studio [Ubuntu]

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio

Ubuntu Eclipse the shortcut for "Clean Project" is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and then press <kbd>N</kbd>.

Question: What is the shortcut in Ubuntu Android Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

summarizing Shortcuts - Android Studio :

**Editing**

```
Ctrl + Space Basic code completion (the name of any class, 
 method or variable)
Ctrl + Shift + Space Smart code completion (filters the list of methods 
 and variables by expected type)
Ctrl + Shift + Enter Complete statement
Ctrl + P Parameter info (within method call arguments)
Ctrl + Q Quick documentation lookup
Shift + F1 External Doc
Ctrl + mouse over code Brief Info
Ctrl + F1 Show descriptions of error or warning at caret
Alt + Insert Generate code... (Getters, Setters, Constructors, 
 hashCode/equals, toString)
Ctrl + O Override methods
Ctrl + I Implement methods
Ctrl + Alt + T Surround with… (if..else, try..catch, for, 
 synchronized, etc.)
Ctrl + / Comment/uncomment with line comment
Ctrl + Shift + / Comment/uncomment with block comment
Ctrl + W Select successively increasing code blocks
Ctrl + Shift + W Decrease current selection to previous state
Alt + Q Context info
Alt + Enter Show intention actions and quick-fixes
Ctrl + Alt + L Reformat code
Ctrl + Alt + O Optimize imports
Ctrl + Alt + I Auto-indent line(s)
Tab / Shift + Tab Indent/unindent selected lines
Ctrl + X or Shift + Delete Cut current line or selected block to clipboard
Ctrl + C or Ctrl + Insert Copy current line or selected block to clipboard
Ctrl + V or Shift + Insert Paste from clipboard
Ctrl + Shift + V Paste from recent buffers...
Ctrl + D Duplicate current line or selected block
Ctrl + Y Delete line at caret
Ctrl + Shift + J Smart line join
Ctrl + Enter Smart line split
Shift + Enter Start new line
Ctrl + Shift + U Toggle case for word at caret or selected block
Ctrl + Shift + ] / [ Select till code block end/start
Ctrl + Delete Delete to word end
Ctrl + Backspace Delete to word start
Ctrl + NumPad+/- Expand/collapse code block
Ctrl + Shift + NumPad+ Expand all
Ctrl + Shift + NumPad- Collapse all
Ctrl + F4 Close active editor tab
```

**Search/Replace**

```
Double Shift Search everywhere
Ctrl + F Find
F3 Find next
Shift + F3 Find previous
Ctrl + R Replace
Ctrl + Shift + F Find in path
Ctrl + Shift + R Replace in path
Ctrl + Shift + S Search structurally (Ultimate Edition only)
Ctrl + Shift + M Replace structurally (Ultimate Edition only)
```

**Usage Search**

```
Alt + F7 / Ctrl + F7 Find usages / Find usages in file
Ctrl + Shift + F7 Highlight usages in file
Ctrl + Alt + F7 Show usages
```

**Compile and Run**

```
Ctrl + F9 Make project (compile modifed and dependent)
Ctrl + Shift + F9 Compile selected file, package or module
Alt + Shift + F10 Select configuration and run
Alt + Shift + F9 Select configuration and debug
Shift + F10 Run
Shift + F9 Debug
Ctrl + Shift + F10 Run context configuration from editor
```

**Debugging**

```
F8 Step over
F7 Step into
Shift + F7 Smart step into
Shift + F8 Step out
Alt + F9 Run to cursor
Alt + F8 Evaluate expression
F9 Resume program
Ctrl + F8 Toggle breakpoint
Ctrl + Shift + F8 View breakpoints
```

**Navigation**

```
Ctrl + N Go to class
Ctrl + Shift + N Go to file
Ctrl + Alt + Shift + N Go to symbol
Alt + Right/Left Go to next/previous editor tab
F12 Go back to previous tool window
Esc Go to editor (from tool window)
Shift + Esc Hide active or last active window
Ctrl + Shift + F4 Close active run/messages/find/... tab
Ctrl + G Go to line
Ctrl + E Recent files popup
Ctrl + Alt + Left/Right Navigate back/forward
Ctrl + Shift + Backspace Navigate to last edit location
Alt + F1 Select current file or symbol in any view
Ctrl + B or Ctrl + Click Go to declaration
Ctrl + Alt + B Go to implementation(s)
Ctrl + Shift + I Open quick definition lookup
Ctrl + Shift + B Go to type declaration
Ctrl + U Go to super-method/super-class
Alt + Up/Down Go to previous/next method
Ctrl + ] / [ Move to code block end/start
Ctrl + F12 File structure popup
Ctrl + H Type hierarchy
Ctrl + Shift + H Method hierarchy
Ctrl + Alt + H Call hierarchy
F2 / Shift + F2 Next/previous highlighted error
F4 / Ctrl + Enter Edit source / View source
Alt + Home Show navigation bar
F11 Toggle bookmark
Ctrl + F11 Toggle bookmark with mnemonic
Ctrl + #[0-9] Go to numbered bookmark
Shift + F11 Show bookmarks
```

**Refactoring**

```
F5 Copy
F6 Move
Alt + Delete Safe Delete
Shift + F6 Rename
Ctrl + F6 Change Signature
Ctrl + Alt + N Inline
Ctrl + Alt + M Extract Method
Ctrl + Alt + V Extract Variable
Ctrl + Alt + F Extract Field
Ctrl + Alt + C Extract Constant 
Ctrl + Alt + P Extract Parameter
```

**VCS/Local History**

```
Ctrl + K Commit project to VCS
Ctrl + T Update project from VCS
Alt + Shift + C View recent changes
Alt + BackQuote (`) ‘VCS’ quick popup
```

**Live Templates**

```
Ctrl + Alt + J Surround with Live Template
Ctrl + J Insert Live Template
iter Iteration according to Java SDK 1.5 style
inst Check object type with instanceof and downcast it
itco Iterate elements of java.util.Collection
itit Iterate elements of java.util.Iterator
itli Iterate elements of java.util.List
psf public static final thr throw new
```

**General**

```
Alt + #[0-9] Open corresponding tool window
Ctrl + S Save all
Ctrl + Alt + Y Synchronize
Ctrl + Shift + F12 Toggle maximizing editor
Alt + Shift + F Add to Favorites
Alt + Shift + I Inspect current file with current profile
Ctrl + BackQuote (`) Quick switch current scheme
Ctrl + Alt + S Open Settings dialog
Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S Open Project Structure dialog
Ctrl + Shift + A Find Action
Ctrl + Tab Switch between tabs and tool window
```

Comment: nice to see all the short cuts :)

Comment: @KOTIOS, You asked a specific question, answered with a text which does not provide an answer to your question and excepted it. This is not how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 9):

You can set your own shortcut not only to Project Clean, but pretty much to anything in Android Studio. Here's an example for Project Clean shortcut:

- `CTRL + SHIFT + A` (Windows or Linux) or `CMD + SHIFT + A` (OS X) to launch action search, type `Shortcut`

  [image]
- Search for `Clean` in top right search box, double click `Clean Project`, select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`

  [image]
- Type your desired shortcut in the appeared dialog and click `OK`. Be careful with conflicting shortcuts!

  [image]`

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio / IntelliJ Mac see here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf

For the above Android Studio / IntelliJ Windows / Linux shortcuts see here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Good reference to have by your desk.